# Concat 2 created element into html attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, concatenation

How can I concat 2 dynamic created HTML elements (var foo + bar) in jquery into html attribute?
Expected result: `<div class="form-control" data-trigger="fileinput"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file fileinput-exists"></i> <span class="fileinput-filename"></span></div>`

But I got: `<div class="form-control" data-trigger="fileinput">[object Object][object Object]</div>`

```
var foo = $('<i></i>', {
    'class': 'glyphicon glyphicon-file fileinput-exists'
});
var bar = $('<span></span>', {
    'class': 'fileinput-filename'
});
var formControl = $('<div></div>', {
    'class': 'form-control',
    'data-trigger': 'fileinput',
    'html': foo + bar
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch the Outer HTML of `foo` and `bar`

```
var foo = $('<i>123</i>', {
    'class': 'glyphicon glyphicon-file fileinput-exists'
});

var bar = $('<span>456</span>', {
    'class': 'fileinput-filename'
});
var formControl = $('<div></div>', {
    'class': 'form-control',
    'data-trigger': 'fileinput',
    'html': foo[0].outerHTML + bar[0].outerHTML
});
```

`outerHTML` [browser compatability](http://caniuse.com/#search=outerHTML)

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ub4wdht0/)**

Comment: Thank you, btw another solution is by use `.append(foo).append(bar);`

Comment: Yes you can also do that. If it solves your problem please consider voting it up and marking it as correct answer.

Comment: Yes this is possible solution, unfortunately at the end both approach goes to big mess, so I decided to write it as plain string...